# Cannot add build to submit app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, release, xcode6

Hell everyone,

I have validated and submitted my build via Xcode to iTunes Connect. However, it seems iTunes doesn't recognize my new builds, so I couldn't use them to submit for review. As you can see that iTunes recognized version 1.0 and 1.0.1 which I had used Xcode 5.1 to submit, for version 1.0.2 and 1.0.3 I had used Xcode 6 and got the issue. I haven't seen this problem before, what's wrong with my build? Does I have to use Xcode 5 to submit app again? Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem just now,and I solved it.
Perhaps it was caused by new itunesconnect and it takes time before your build become available for review.
After waiting for about 1 hour,my build become Inactive and can be added for review.
It's really stupid.

Comment: @Xstian I mean it was caused by new itunesconnect and it takes time before your build become available for review.So just wait about 1 hour or more,and your build will be available.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but after waiting for over 6 hours, nothing changes.